# Terraform variable list of key value pairs for environment variables of batch job

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I've specified a batch job as:

```
resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "batch_job" {
  name = "${var.name}"
  type = "container"

  container_properties = <<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
{
    "command": ["${var.command_first}", "${var.command_second}"],
    "image": "${var.image_repo}:${var.image_tag}",
    "memory": ${var.memory},
    "vcpus": 1,
    "jobRoleArn": "${var.job_role_arn}",
    "environment": "${var.environment}"

}
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
}
```

where var.environment comes from the input variable

```
variable "environment" {
}
```

which in my terraform values file I have as

```
environment = {
[
      {"name" : "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION",  "value" : "region-val"}
  ]
}
```

But it doesn't like that format.

If I specify the batch job like this:

```
resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "batch_job" {
  name = "${var.name}"
  type = "container"

  container_properties = <<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
{
    "command": ["${var.command_first}", "${var.command_second}"],
    "image": "${var.image_repo}:${var.image_tag}",
    "memory": ${var.memory},
    "vcpus": 1,
    "jobRoleArn": "${var.job_role_arn}",
    "environment":  [
      {"name" : "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION",  "value" : "region-val"}
  ]

}
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
}
```

it works so the issue is when I move this to the variables file it doesn't work.

What should the format be and how should it be used it the batch job definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In terraform resource, aws_batch_job_definition, the argument container_properties is supposed to be a json document and **environment** is a key in it. So if you would like to pass a list of env variables to it then you should jsonify the list variable which has the values and only then it would be able to identify proper json data otherwise it will always throw exception.

Terraform has inbuilt function jsonencode() which can be used to jsonify list, map etc.

Refer: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html

To work your terraform code, I have modified this a little bit and you will get an idea on how to take it from here,

```
variable environmentvar {
  type = list
  default = [
    {"name":"AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", "value": "region-val"},
  ]
}

resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "batch_job" {
  name = "${var.name}"
  type = "container"

  container_properties = <<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
{
    "command": ["${var.command_first}", "${var.command_second}"],
    "image": "${var.image_repo}:${var.image_tag}",
    "memory": ${var.memory},
    "vcpus": 1,
    "jobRoleArn": "${var.job_role_arn}",
    "environment": ${jsonencode(var.environmentvar)}
}
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
}
```

**environmentvar** must be a list of env variables and which in turn is a dictionary. So you have to define it with the list you require

**${jsonencode(var.environmentvar)}** jsonify the env var list and generate the data required to be passed to the **environment** key of container properties.